# Where does the "Set Working Directory" feature in RStudio come from ? Does it come from Rstudio or is it from an add-in?

Tags: rstudio, right-click, working-directory

I have just noticed that one can set the working directory with a right-click on the tab of a .R file in Rstudio.

[image]

Is this a new feature of RStudio or does it come from an add-in (added when installing a package) ?

Comment: it looks like a new feature, but it just runs `setwd()` on whatever directory the script is saved in.

Comment: Yes I know what this features does

Comment: You were asking if it is added when installing a package. The answer is no, it works automatically because it uses a base function.